# Trivial valuation

Tags: valuation-theory

I'm pretty sure trivial valuation over a field cannot be extended to a non-trivial one in a bigger field. Is there a simple way to show this without using the sledge hammer theorem on valuation extension over complete valued field?

Answer (score 9):

Sure it can.  Consider the x-adic valuation on the field of Laurent series $k((x))$ over a field $k$, extending the trivial absolute value on $k$.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you meant for the extension $L/K$ to be algebraic, in which case it is true that any extension of the trivial valuation on $K$ to $L$ is trivial.  This clearly reduces to
the case of a finite extension, and then -- since a trivially valued field is complete --
this follows from the uniqueness of the extended valuation in a finite extension of a complete field.  Maybe you view this as part of the sledgehammer, but it's not really the heavy part: see e.g. p. 16 of

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter2.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter2.pdf)

for the proof.  (These notes then spend several more pages establishing the existence part of the result.)

**Addendum**: Conversely, if $L/K$ is transcendental, then there exists a nontrivial extension on $L$ which is trivial on $K$.  Indeed, let $t$ be an element of $L$ which is
transcendental over $K$, and extend the trivial valuation to $K(t)$ by taking $v_{\infty}(P/Q) = deg(Q) - deg(P)$.  (The completion of $K$ with respect to $v_{\infty}$ is the Laurent series field $K((t))$, so this is really the same construction as in Cam's answer.)  Then I prove* in the same set of notes that any non-Archimedean valuation can be extended to an arbitrary field extension, so $v$ extends all the way to $L$ and is certainly nontrivial there, being already nontrivial on $K(t)$.

*: not for the first time, of course, though I had a hard time finding exactly this result in the texts I was using to prepare my course.  (This **does** use the sledgehammer.)